# Has this code a memory leak?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I think I have a memory leak in my WPF code, and I'm doing tests. The part I'm not sure if it has problems is this one:

```
public void MakeFadeIn(Window window, FrameworkElement target,  MakeFadeCallBack makeFadeCallBack, double from, double to)
{
    DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(from, to, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)) {BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)};
    Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();

    string storyBoardName = "storyBoardMakeFadeIn" + CreateRandomNum();
    Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, target);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath("(Opacity)"));
    storyBoard.Children.Add(anim1);

    _eventHandler = (sndr, evtArgs) =>
    {
        window.Resources.Remove(storyBoardName);
        storyBoard.Completed -= _eventHandler;          
        if (makeFadeCallBack != null)
            makeFadeCallBack();
    };

    storyBoard.Completed += _eventHandler;                
    window.Resources.Add(storyBoardName, storyBoard);

    storyBoard.Begin();
}

public Storyboard CreateAnimationStoryBoard(Window window, Grid gridContent, FrameworkElement startElement, Image imageOrig, BitmapImage bitmapImageOrig, double endPointX, double endPointY, double toScale)
{
    GeneralTransform gt = startElement.TransformToAncestor(window);
    Point rootPoint = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    Image image = new Image
    {
        Source = bitmapImageOrig,
        Opacity = 0.8,
        Height = imageOrig.DesiredSize.Height,
        Width = imageOrig.DesiredSize.Width,
        Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
        Margin = new Thickness(rootPoint.X, rootPoint.Y, 0, 0),
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5)
    };
    gridContent.Children.Add(image);

    TransformGroup transGroup = new TransformGroup();

    ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform();
    TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
    transGroup.Children.Add(scale);
    transGroup.Children.Add(trans); // BE CAREFUL, order is important, Scale ALWAYS before trans

    image.RenderTransform = transGroup;
    window.RegisterName("translateArticleToOrder", transGroup);

    DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(endPointX - rootPoint.X, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4));
    DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(endPointY - rootPoint.Y - image.Height, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4));
    DoubleAnimation animScaleX = new DoubleAnimation(toScale, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4));
    DoubleAnimation animScaleY = new DoubleAnimation(toScale, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4));

    Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
    window.Resources.Add("storyBoardArticleToOrder", storyBoard);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(storyBoard, "translateArticleToOrder");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath("Children[1].X"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, new PropertyPath("Children[1].Y"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animScaleX, new PropertyPath("Children[0].ScaleX"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animScaleY, new PropertyPath("Children[0].ScaleY"));

    storyBoard.Children.Add(anim1);
    storyBoard.Children.Add(anim2);
    storyBoard.Children.Add(animScaleX);
    storyBoard.Children.Add(animScaleY);

    _eventHandler = (sndr, evtArgs) =>
    {
        storyBoard.Completed -= _eventHandler;
        window.Resources.Remove("storyBoardArticleToOrder");
        gridContent.Children.Remove(image);
        window.UnregisterName("translateArticleToOrder");                
    };
    storyBoard.Completed += _eventHandler;
    return storyBoard;
}
```

I use these two functions to create anymations on the fly, but I'm not sure if doing this way is creating Memory Leaks.

Can someone tell me if this code has leaks or not? I was suspecting on the EventHandlers "completed" and also adding the storyboard to the windows.Resources.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think images are something that have resources you need to dispose of

Comment: Not sure if that is the problem. This "Image" is the WPF component, not the Image from Windows Forms. They don't have a Dispose class.

Comment: If it goes 3-4 days before an OOM then I know this is not really and answer but but restart it every day.  It does not look like a program that needs to run 24 hours a day.  If you are getting on OOM but it appears to not be using a lot of memory the problem could be contiguous memory.   Not really an answer and that is why it is a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this. It seems it was a problem with .NET Framework 3.5

I added this:

```
new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters());
```

to App.xaml constructor and the problem is gone.